# PHP parse url for variables

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, get

I am building a tool that runs on my localhost that helps to put static webpages together a little faster. Security is not an issue since this is only going to run locally.

First I have an `include` file called `components.php` file with variables for page sections like this:

```
$slide="Pretend this is markup for a Slider";
$port="Pretend this is markup for a set of portfolio images";
$para="<p>Just another paragraph</p>";
$h1="<h1>This is a Header</h1>";
```

Then my url looks like this:

```
//only calling 3 of the 4 sections
localhost/mysite/index.php?sections=h1-slide-para
```

And my index file has this:

```
include 'components.php'

$sections =  @$_GET['sections'];
$section = explode($sections,"-");
foreach ($section as $row){
echo $row;
}
```

The goal here is to build the `components.php` file up with rows I am always using so I can quickly throw page layouts together right from the address bar of my browser. I am just not sure how to `echo` the variables once I `explode` them so that `index.php` contains only the markup I have called from the `components.php` file.

Comment: So what is your question now? How you can access the variables from your `components.php` file with your `$_GET` variable ?

Comment: Put your templaty excerpts into an array, or use `$row` as variable variable.

Comment: `explode($sections,"-");` should be `explode('-', $sections);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`variable variables`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to access the variables from your `components.php` file (Also switch the arguments in `explode()`, they are the wrong way around), e.g.

```
$section = explode("-", $sections);

foreach ($section as $row) {
    echo $$row;
       //^^ See here the double dollar sign
}
```

---

An alternative solution would be to change your file to `ini` format, e.g.

```
slide="Pretend this is markup for a Slider"
port="Pretend this is markup for a set of portfolio images"
para="<p>Just another paragraph</p>"
h1="<h1>This is a Header</h1>"
```

And then get it into an array with [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php):

```
$arr = parse_ini_file("components.ini");
                                //^^^ Note, that you now work with an .ini file    

$sections =  @$_GET['sections'];
$section = explode("-", $sections);
foreach ($section as $row) {
    echo $arr[$row];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your strings into an array:

```
$sections = [
    'slide' => "Pretend this is markup for a Slider",
    'port' => "Pretend this is markup for a set of portfolio images",
    'para' => "<p>Just another paragraph</p>",
    'h1' => "<h1>This is a Header</h1>",
];
```

Then, reference those sections by name:

```
foreach (explode('-', $_GET['sections']) as $section){
    echo $sections[$section];
}
```

Comment: So used to `implode()`, that both ways works, but in `explode()` the delimiter is first :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Oh crap, that was OP's mistake too, then =/

Comment: yes, I think we can blame the heat for this. It's like 37°C here (= +/- 100°F)

Comment: It's not *that* hot here, but the humidity itself is killer :)

Answer (score 0):

firstly instead of

```
$section = explode($sections, "-");
```

use

```
$section = explode("-", $sections);
```

and also

```
foreach ($section as $row){
    echo eval('return $'. $row . ';');
}
```